# how to union list of dicts python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have the list of dicts like:

```
list_of_dict = [{},
                {'a': 2},
                {'a': 3},
                {'b': 2, 'c': 4}]
```

and want to create a new list like:

```
new_list = [{'a': 2, 'b': 2, 'c':4},
            {'a': 3}]
```

where dicts are combined if they don't have keys intersection or values of intersected keys are the same.

I take first pair, check intersected keys (and values if intersection is) then delete this pair and replace with new dict. When should I stop?

```
list_of_dict = [{},
            {'a': 2},
            {'a': 3},
            {'b': 2, 'c': 4}]


keys_a = set(list_of_dict[0].keys())
keys_b = set(list_of_dict[1].keys())
intersection = keys_a & keys_b
while ??:
    if not intersection or //check intersected is equal//:
        list_of_dict[0].update(list_of_dict[1])
        list_of_dict.pop(1)
print list_of_dict
```

Solution for 2.7

```
import copy

dcts = []
buffer = {}
for i in list_of_dict:
    if not i or any(j in buffer for j in i.keys()):
        buffer = i
    else:
        new_ = copy.deepcopy(i)
        new_.update(buffer)
        buffer = copy.deepcopy(new_)
        dcts.append(buffer)
print dcts
```

Comment: What determines whether the `b` and `c` entries get added to `a:2` or `a:3`?

Comment: Does the entire dict have the be added to the same one?  Or could the `b` and `c` entries wind up in different prior dicts?

Comment: I do not want to make something difficult, so first acceptable dict union to is is ok

Comment: entire dict only

Comment: @user9642832 do you care if `b` and `c` get added to the most recent `a`?

Comment: @chrisz  no, its ok

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution, checks if any keys in the current dictionary exist in the buffer, and if so creates a new list entry, otherwise it merges the current dictionary with the buffer:

```
dcts = []
buffer = {}
for i in list_of_dict:
    if any(j in buffer for j in i.keys()):
        dcts.append(buffer)
        buffer = i
    else:
        buffer = {**i, **buffer}

dcts.append(buffer)
print(dcts)
```

Output:

```
[{'a': 2}, {'b': 2, 'c': 4, 'a': 3}]
```

Comment: Thanks! I've added version for 2.7 Python, hope its right